# How to change CodeIgniter's URI segments based on a language

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Question:**
How could I make my URL language specific, for example:

- **English**
  www.website.com / controller-in-en / method-in-en
- **Other language**
  www.website.com / controller-in-oth-lang / method-in-oth-lang
  (I want this URL to be automatically redirected to www.website.com / controller-in-en / method-in-en based on a 'controller-in-en' and 'method-in-en' translation in a language file).

**Additional information:**
In the future, I plan to redirect users for different languages to different subdomains, e.g. lt.website.com, but right now I want  URI segments to be translated depending on users language.

I want to make clear that:

1. I already know how to create a language switcher and change
   language.
2. I DO NOT want language code to be included in the url,
   like '/en' or '/lt'.

**My (bad) ideas:**
I thought this could be done via translated routing addresses 
`$route[lang('url_market')] = 'market/index';` 
but when routing is done, language library is not yeat loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Based On @AdrienXL answer, Here's a sample without using a database.

```
$config['routes_translation']['en'] = array(
'home' => 'home'
);

$config['routes_translation']['fr'] = array(
'home' => 'accueil'
);
```

Obviously, You know the language for the user using a session, And you have the controller name, You can get the translation easily by accessing the config item.

```
$translatedNamed = $config['routes_translation'][$language_code][$controller]
```

which should give you 'home' for en & 'accueil' for fr

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is through the db.

Build a table that looks like this :

routes_translation

```
*****************************************
*id |  controller   | translation | lang*
*****************************************
* 1 | home          |    home     | en  *
* 2 | home          |  accueil    | fr  *
                   ...
*****************************************
```

Then in your routes.php

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('routes_translation');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[$row->translation] = $row->controller;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do the same by requiring translations from a file (translation file to be precise) instead of a database?

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas You can accomplish the same thing using a config file by having a config array for each language having the controller name as index & translation as value.

Comment: @ahmad Could you provide a sample code for this? And submit it as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: I have provided an example config array based on @AdrienXL solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple....

1. Get the user select language either from db or store it in SESSION
2. Pass the selected laguage while loading the language library

Eg: $this->lang->load("message",$SESSION['selected_language']);

Comment: These instructions explain how to load the language file. What I need is to change the routing depending on the language stored in a session.

Comment: I understand that. What I am looking to do, is to create an automatic route to, let's say 'market' controller, but in other language it may be called different. I would like my application to display 'market' controller, but it should be accessed through, say 'rinka' URI segment if it's in lithuanian language.